# Why am I getting different results from the same code?

Tags: mdwtools

I'm using the `syntax.sty` part of the `mdwtools` package to produce the code in `working.tex`. This works fine in its own file, but when I put the exact same code in files `main.tex` and `chap2.tex`, I get a bunch of errors. How can I be getting errors in one situation and not the other? I thought it was because `mdwtools` wasn't installed, but `working.tex` shows that this isn't the case. Can anyone help with this? The minimal code for the 3 files is below:

`working.tex`:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{syntax}

\begin{document}
This is an example grammar in EBNF: 
\begin{grammar}
<statement> ::= <ident> ‘=’ <expr>
\alt ‘for’ <ident> ‘=’ <expr> ‘to’ <expr> ‘do’ <statement>
\alt ‘\{’ <stat-list> ‘\}’
\alt <empty>
<stat-list> ::= <statement> ‘;’ <stat-list> | <statement>
\end{grammar}
\end{document}
```

`main.tex`:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage{syntax}

\begin{document}
\include{chap2}
\end{document}
```

`chap2.tex`:

```
% Chapter 2: The Language
This is an example grammar in EBNF: 
\begin{grammar}
<statement> ::= <ident> ‘=’ <expr>
\alt ‘for’ <ident> ‘=’ <expr> ‘to’ <expr> ‘do’ <statement>
\alt ‘\{’ <stat-list> ‘\}’
\alt <empty>
<stat-list> ::= <statement> ‘;’ <stat-list> | <statement>
\end{grammar}
```

Something else to note is that this does not happen in Overleaf, but only on my local machine, and it only happens in a specific document, because it works after transplanting it to a fresh document, but not with the full document; just that part of it.

The error messages that I am getting are shown in the following screen capture:
[image: LaTeX errors]

Comment: 1. We don't have access rights to your project. 2. Please post the code necessary to reproduce your issue in a minimal way here, not on a third party site. If this isn't possible you can also contact Overleaf's support, which can access your project if you give permission.

Comment: Oh, OK. I did that because it was 3 separate files. Is it OK to post it all?

Comment: You should try to minimize the code you provide to only include what is necessary to reproduce your issue. Take a look at: [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228).

Comment: I have tried to produce an MWE and have edited my post

Comment: I can't reproduce your issue with the code you provide. For me both give identical results on a local TeX Live installation.

Comment: That is strange. I'm at a loss as to the cause.

Comment: Perhaps, posting the error messages you get (or, if they are too many, only the first thereof) may help other people to guess what is going wrong on your computer.

Comment: I have edited my post to include the errors.

Comment: The third error from the bottom says that LaTeX is looking for the file `Chapters/chap`.  Is this from a previous iteration of tracking down the error?  You may need to simply delete the aux files and try again.